# Dynamic scan for a string : C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider below code I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

void dynamicScan(char** str)
{
 *str=(char*) malloc(10*sizeof(char));
 int i=0,j=1,k=0,c;
 do{
 c=getchar();
 *(*str+i)=c;
 i++;
 k++;
 if(k >=10)
 {
     j++;
     *str=(char*) realloc(*str,j*sizeof(char)); //Edited: Line 17 here
     assert(*str);
     printf("Resized to %d bytes\n",j*10);
     k=0;
 }
 }while(c != '\n');

 *(*str+i)='\0';
}


int main()
{

char* dynamicName,*dynAdd;

printf("-------------------------\n");
printf("Enter a Dynamic Name: ");
dynamicScan(&dynamicName);
printf("Dynamic Name: %s\n",dynamicName);
printf("Enter a Dynamic Address: ");
dynamicScan(&dynAdd);
printf("Dynamic Address: %s\n",dynAdd);


free(dynamicName);
free(dynAdd);


return 0;
}
```

I am trying to implement dynamic scannig of a character array. It works fine.
I have seen the code running to large arrays .e.g say resized to `80 bytes`.
But many times code is crashing even for resizing to `20 bytes`.
Below is the `dgb` output. I am not able to figure out, what is going wrong, Can any help to debug?

```
(gdb) run
    The program being debugged has been started already.
    Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
    Starting program: /cygdrive/d/cPractice/getS.exe
    [New Thread 8820.0x102c]
    [New Thread 8820.0x3d0]
    -------------------------
    Enter a Dynamic Name: Andrew Thomas from UK
    Resized to 20 bytes
    Resized to 30 bytes
    Dynamic Name: Andrew Thomas from UK

    Enter a Dynamic Address: I was living in scotland; now in united kingdom
    Resized to 20 bytes
    Resized to 30 bytes

    Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
    0x00401206 in dynamicScan (str=0xd0) at getS.c:17
    17               *str=(char*) realloc(*str,j*sizeof(char));
    (gdb)
```

Comment: Ugh, you should really indent your code before posting, and also remove commented out sections, and also indicate which like that line 17 is.

Comment: @hyde edited.. anyways got it.. wat was missing as pointed by jwodder in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you should change this line:

```
*str=(char*) realloc(*str,j*sizeof(char));
```

to this:

```
*str=(char*) realloc(*str,j*10*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Please read: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845). Also, `sizeof(char)` is per definitionem 1.